# Has the Eye of Agamotto ever been lost or destroyed in the comics?

Tags: marvel, comics

In the MCU we have seen that as of *Avengers: Infinity War* Doctor Strange has now;

> lost the Eye of Agamotto with the Time Stone having been destroyed.

I realise that in the comics the stone is not an Infinity Stone but has there been any precedence for Doctor Strange losing the Eye or having it destroyed?

Comment: I’m not sure, but I’m the MCU, wasn’t “the eye of Agomotto” the pendant? The sorcerers seriously called the time stone (which they all knew was the time stone) as the eye of agomotto? ‍♂️

Comment: @Shreedhar _"Wong: Wise choice. You’ll wear the Eye of Agamotto once you’ve mastered its powers. Until then, best not to walk the streets wearing an Infinity Stone."_ The Eye appears to be the "whole thing"... they knew it contained the Time Stone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Eye of Agamotto is destroyed in *The Heroic Age: The New Avengers* Issue 6 when Doctor Voodoo, Jericho Drumm, sacrifices himself to destroy Agamotto along with the Eye and Orb when Wolverine appears to be losing the fight against him.

[image: _The Heroic Age: The New Avengers_ Issue 6 Jericho sacrifices himself] [image: _The Heroic Age: The New Avengers_ Issue 6 Agamotto is destroyed]
<sub>*Click images to enlarge.*</sub>

[image: _The Heroic Age: The New Avengers_ Issue 6 the Eye of Agamotto is destroyed]